# Sending Commands from Jupyter/IPython running on EC2 to EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, jupyter, amazon-emr, jupyter-notebook

Can we send commands from Jupyter/IPython notebook running on AWS EC2 to AWS EMR having our code of word count ?
I have followed the following url for installation of 
[Jupyter on EC2.](http://blog.impiyush.me/2015/02/running-ipython-notebook-server-on-aws.html)
There is another link which installs [Jupyter on EMR and performs Word Count](https://github.com/JustGiving/raven-aws-emr-spark-jupyter)

However i want to seperate the Jupyter to come on EC2 and Word Count to execute on EMR. Is there any way that this could be done ?

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789394/setting-up-jupyter-pyspark-to-work-between-ec2-and-emr/72713776#72713776

Answer (score 0):

This AWS Big Data Blog post for running Zeppelin on an external EC2 host connected to an EMR cluster may help you with achieving something similar with Jupyter instead of Zeppelin:

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx2HJD3Z74J2U8U/Running-an-External-Zeppelin-Instance-using-S3-Backed-Notebooks-with-Spark-on-Am